# When do I need to install root certificate on the client trust store?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

I have a https server with following the certificate chain : Root CA -> Intermediate CA -> server certificate

I noticed that for the client (eg. browser) trusts the server I need to install in Windows: Root CA in Trusted Root CA store, Intermediate CA in Trusted Intermediate CA store.

Why do I need to install Root CA and not only Intermediate CA ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the Root CA tells your browser to trust the Root CA, and any certificates signed (directly or indirectly) by the Root CA.

If you don't install the Root CA, then your browser will not trust the Root CA, and therefore it will not trust the Intermediate CA, and therefore it will not trust the Server Certificate.

Comment: Thank you, can I just install intermediates to trust the server ?

Comment: No, you need to install the entire certificate chain...